# Python: Parse Json to find matching lines matching few keys

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a Json which looks like this.

```
{"processId":"p1","userId":"user1","reportName":"report1","threadId":"12234", "some_other_keys":"respective values"}
{"userId":"user1","processId":"p1","reportName":"report1","threadId":"12335", "some_other_keys":"respective values"}
{"reportName":"report2","processId":"p1","userId":"user1","threadId":"12434", "some_other_keys":"respective values"}
{"threadId":"12734", "some_other_keys":"respective values", "processId":"p1","userId":"user2","reportName":"report1"}
{"processId":"p1","reportName":"report1","threadId":"12534", "some_other_keys":"respective values","userId":"user2"}
{"processId":"p1","userId":"user1","reportName":"report2","threadId":"12934", "some_other_keys":"respective values"}
{"processId":"p1","userId":"user1","reportName":"report1","threadId":"12834", "some_other_keys":"respective values"}
{"processId":"p1","userId":"user1","reportName":"report2","threadId":"12634", "some_other_keys":"respective values"}
```

**Objective:** write a function which returns all different sets of lines which has same values of "processId","userId","reportName".

So, in this particular example, the function should return three different sets.

Set1 ( for "processId":"p1","userId":"user1","reportName":"report1"):

```
{"processId":"p1","userId":"user1","reportName":"report1","threadId":"12234", "some_other_keys":"respective values"}*
{"userId":"user1","processId":"p1","reportName":"report1","threadId":"12335", "some_other_keys":"respective values"}*
{"processId":"p1","userId":"user1","reportName":"report1","threadId":"12834", "some_other_keys":"respective values"}
```

Set2 ("processId":"p1","userId":"user1","reportName":"report2"):

```
{"reportName":"report2","processId":"p1","userId":"user1","threadId":"12434", "some_other_keys":"respective values"}*
{"processId":"p1","userId":"user1","reportName":"report2","threadId":"12934", "some_other_keys":"respective values"}
{"processId":"p1","userId":"user1","reportName":"report2","threadId":"12634", "some_other_keys":"respective values"}
```

Set3 ("processId":"p1","userId":"user2","reportName":"report1"):

```
{"threadId":"12734", "some_other_keys":"respective values", "processId":"p1","userId":"user2","reportName":"report1"}
{"processId":"p1","reportName":"report1","threadId":"12534", "some_other_keys":"respective values","userId":"user2"}
```

So, one function is returning three sets (this can be more or less also depending on the number of matching sets)

I need a solution for the above problem as a (a) performance efficient code (b) code with less number of lines, as I'll be processing a large number of lines. So want my code to run faster and also the code should be with fewer lines.

I already have a solution for this problem with multiple if conditions and for loops (I'm using Python json to parse the json and get the elements). But wanted a more efficient code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, use `itertools.groupby` with `operator.itemgetter`:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby

keys = ["processId","userId","reportName"]

f = lambda x: itemgetter(*keys)(x)
srt = sorted(d, key=f)
for k, g in groupby(srt, key=f):
    print(k)
    print(list(g))
```

Output:

```
('p1', 'user1', 'report1')
[{'some_other_keys': 'respective values', 'threadId': '12234', 'userId': 'user1', 'processId': 'p1', 'reportName': 'report1'},
 {'some_other_keys': 'respective values', 'threadId': '12335', 'userId': 'user1', 'processId': 'p1', 'reportName': 'report1'}, 
 {'some_other_keys': 'respective values', 'threadId': '12834', 'userId': 'user1', 'processId': 'p1', 'reportName': 'report1'}]
('p1', 'user1', 'report2')
[{'some_other_keys': 'respective values', 'threadId': '12434', 'userId': 'user1', 'processId': 'p1', 'reportName': 'report2'}, 
 {'some_other_keys': 'respective values', 'threadId': '12934', 'userId': 'user1', 'processId': 'p1', 'reportName': 'report2'}, 
 {'some_other_keys': 'respective values', 'threadId': '12634', 'userId': 'user1', 'processId': 'p1', 'reportName': 'report2'}]
('p1', 'user2', 'report1')
[{'threadId': '12734', 'userId': 'user2', 'reportName': 'report1', 'processId': 'p1', 'some_other_keys': 'respective values'}, 
 {'some_other_keys': 'respective values', 'threadId': '12534', 'userId': 'user2', 'processId': 'p1', 'reportName': 'report1'}]
```

Comment: Hi, I wanted to get more understanding of what the line **f = lambda x: itemgetter(*keys)(x)** doing here. I tried to print the value of "f" but it prints something like this - 
**<function function_name.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x030464A8>** (my code is inside a function).
Need help with more understanding of the line with lambda.